# Is Gradle build scan secure?

Tags: gradle, privacy

I think Gradle Build Scan is a nice feature. It would be super effective to cooperate with team on debugging a Gradle configuration by looking at a project build scan.
But I'm not sure if I may publish scans of a private project.

Does Gradle collect any secrets when publishing a build scan? Anything specific to worry about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> But I'm not sure if I may publish scans of a private project.

If it's a private project, like proprietary, then I'd suggest [Gradle Enterprise](https://gradle.com/) for extra privacy assurance. Otherwise, you will need to remember to delete the **public** build scan when finished.

> Does Gradle collect any secrets when publishing a build scan?

A build scan collects the following information of your Gradle project:

https://docs.gradle.com/enterprise/gradle-plugin/#captured_information

You will need to do your own due diligence to make sure no secrets that you have in your project fall into any of the captured information.